# unknown key [number_of_shards] for create index

Tags: mongodb, elasticsearch, graylog

I am using api to create indexes in elasticsearch but getting this error.

2022-07-19 05:50:52,098 INFO    [Indices] - Successfully ensured index template log_ls_mnipdbpidathala_modeln_com_rc_jboss_logs_log-template - {}
2022-07-19 05:50:52,102 WARN    [Indices] - Couldn't create index log_ls_mnipdbpidathala_modeln_com_rc_jboss_logs_log_0. Error: {"root_cause":[{"type":"parse_exception","reason":"unknown key [number_of_shards] for create index"}],"type":"parse_exception","reason":"unknown key [number_of_shards] for create index"} - {}
org.graylog2.indexer.ElasticsearchException: {"root_cause":[{"type":"parse_exception","reason":"unknown key [number_of_shards] for create index"}],"type":"parse_exception","reason":"unknown key [number_of_shards] for create index"}
at org.graylog.storage.elasticsearch6.IndicesAdapterES6.create(IndicesAdapterES6.java:218) ~[?:?]
at org.graylog2.indexer.indices.Indices.create(Indices.java:202) ~[graylog.jar:?]
at org.graylog2.indexer.MongoIndexSet.cycle(MongoIndexSet.java:291) ~[graylog.jar:?]
at org.graylog2.indexer.MongoIndexSet.setUp(MongoIndexSet.java:259) ~[graylog.jar:?]
at org.graylog2.periodical.IndexRotationThread.checkAndRepair(IndexRotationThread.java:138) ~[graylog.jar:?]
at org.graylog2.periodical.IndexRotationThread.lambda$doRun$0(IndexRotationThread.java:76) ~[graylog.jar:?]
at java.lang.Iterable.forEach(Iterable.java:75) [?:1.8.0_332]
at org.graylog2.periodical.IndexRotationThread.doRun(IndexRotationThread.java:73) [graylog.jar:?]
at org.graylog2.plugin.periodical.Periodical.run(Periodical.java:94) [graylog.jar:?]
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) [?:1.8.0_332]
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:308) [?:1.8.0_332]
at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180) [?:1.8.0_332]
at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:294) [?:1.8.0_332]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [?:1.8.0_332]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [?:1.8.0_332]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750) [?:1.8.0_332]

Elastic version - 7.10.2

Comment: Give more details your mapping.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your settings are as below:

```
PUT /my-index-000001
{
  "settings": {
    "index": {
      "number_of_shards": 3,  
      "number_of_replicas": 2 
    }
  }
}
```